# Game of Life Segmentation Fault in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

Im new to C, linux etc my code compiles and runs but as soon as I enter my first user inputs I get a segmentation fault. If someone could point out what is wrong with my code that would be very help helpful I think it is either in the 'calculate()' or 'main()' because I tried to allocate memory using 'malloc()' in both of those places.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LIFE_YES 'X'
#define LIFE_NO 'O'

int HEIGHT, WIDTH;
typedef int **TableType;

void printTable(TableType table) {
    int height, width;

        for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
            for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
                    if (table[height][width] == LIFE_YES) {
                        printf("X");
                    } 
            else {
                    printf("-");
                    }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
}

void clearTable(TableType table) {
    int height, width;

        for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
            for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
                    table[height][width] = LIFE_NO;
            }
        }
}

void askUser(TableType tableA) {
    int i;
        int n;
        int height, width;

        printf("Enter the amount of initial organisms: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("Enter dimensions (x y) where organism %d will live: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%d %d", &height, &width);

            tableA[height][width] = LIFE_YES;
        }

        printTable(tableA);
        printf("Generation 0");
}

int getNeighborValue(TableType table, int row, int col) {
        if (row < 0 || row >= HEIGHT || col < 0 || col >= WIDTH || table[row][col] != LIFE_YES ) {
            return 0;
        } 
    else {
            return 1;
        }
}

int getNeighborCount(TableType table, int row, int col) {
        int neighbor = 0;

        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row - 1, col - 1);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row - 1, col);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row - 1, col + 1);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row, col - 1);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row, col + 1);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row + 1, col - 1);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row + 1, col);
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row + 1, col + 1);

        return neighbor;
}

void calculate(TableType tableA) {
        TableType tableB;
        int neighbor, height, width, i;
    tableB= malloc(HEIGHT * sizeof(int*));

    for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
            tableB[i] = malloc(WIDTH * sizeof(int));
    }

        for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
            for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
                    neighbor = getNeighborCount(tableA, height, width);
                    if (neighbor==3) {
                        tableB[height][width] = LIFE_YES;
                    } 
            else if (neighbor == 2 && tableA[height][width] == LIFE_YES) {
                        tableB[height][width] = LIFE_YES;
                    } 
            else {
                        tableB[height][width] = LIFE_NO;
                    }
            }
        }

        for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
            for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
                    tableA[height][width] = tableB[height][width];
            }
    }
    free(tableB);
}

/* test data
void loadTestData(TableType table) {
        table[3][4] = LIFE_YES;
        table[3][5] = LIFE_YES;
        table[3][6] = LIFE_YES;

        table[10][4] = LIFE_YES;
        table[10][5] = LIFE_YES;
        table[10][6] = LIFE_YES;
        table[11][6] = LIFE_YES;
        table[12][5] = LIFE_YES;
}
*/

int main(void) {
    int i;
        char end;
        int generation = 0;

    printf("Enter the amount of rows and columns you want in the grid: ");
    scanf("%i %i\n", &HEIGHT, &WIDTH);

        TableType table = malloc(HEIGHT * sizeof(int*));

    for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
            table[i] = malloc(WIDTH * sizeof(int));
    }

        clearTable(table);
        askUser(table);
        /*loadTestData(table);*/
        printTable(table);

        while (end != 'q') {
            calculate(table);
            printTable(table);
            printf("Generation %d\n", ++generation);
            printf("Press q to quit or 1 to continue: ");
            scanf(" %c", &end);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile your program with `-g` parameter, open it inside gdb (`gdb myprogramname`), run it (`run`) and print backtrace after receiving segfault (`bt`).

Comment: @NemanjaBoric how exactly do I put that in the terminal I normally do gcc -Wall "ProjectName.c" then run it with ./a.out

Comment: If I'm right, it seg faults after you have entered your HEIGHT and WIDTH?

Comment: `gcc -Wall -g "ProjectName.c"` and instead of `./a.out` run gdb: `gdb ./a.out`

Comment: @NemanjaBoric I ran that and all it says is "No Stack".

Comment: @xQuare which method and how should I get rid of it.

Comment: @MelMoore Did you compile it with `-g`? Alternative is just to go step by step by using `next` command.

Comment: @MelMoore No I was just trying to ask which was the last line of code that you are sure to have been executed before the segfault.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric yes I did "gcc -Wall -g PA2.c" then did "gdb ./a.out" followed by "bt"

Comment: @xQuare Yes its right after I enter the HEIGHT and WEIGHT

Comment: @MelMoore You forgot to run the program with `run` command in `gdb`. Run `bt` after you receive segfault.

Comment: Change `scanf("%i %i\n", &HEIGHT, &WIDTH);` -> `scanf("%i%i", &HEIGHT, &WIDTH)`.  The scanf functions automatically skip whitespace for everything except `%c`, and the newline will only screw things up.

Answer (score 0):

In main

```
scanf("%i %i\n", &HEIGHT, &WIDTH);  ==>    scanf("%i %i", &HEIGHT, &WIDTH);
             ^
```

because of that \n you need to enter one more input.avoid it

and segmentation fault in `askUser`

```
tableA[height][width] = LIFE_YES;

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004007c1 in askUser (tableA=0x603010) at seg3.c:49
49                  tableA[height][width] = LIFE_YES;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000004007c1 in askUser (tableA=0x603010) at seg3.c:49
#1  0x0000000000400bf3 in main () at seg3.c:142
(gdb)
```

and here you did not allocate memory but you are accessing.allocate memory first

Comment: @MelMoore easy way fixing is declare globally.  `static int table[max][max];` and avoid passing array as argument. if you dont want to declare globally , you should play with pointers....

Comment: I was trying to use pointers but now im just getting seg faults.

Comment: @MelMoore i always encourage usage of pointers... first complete your program with array and then convert to pointers  see this http://www.cppforschool.com/tutorial/array2.html

Answer (score 0):

It is seg-faulting because of:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
   printf("Enter dimensions (x y) where organism %d will live: ", i + 1);
   scanf("%d %d", &height, &width);
    tableA[height][width] = LIFE_YES;  <--- Here 
}
```

What if the user specified dimension goes out-of-bound beyond the 'HEIGHT' and 'WEIGHT' dimensions you dynamically allocated initially in `main`.

You need to check for the co-ordinates to be non-negative and less than the above dimensions when user enters, if it's not within bound just throw a error message and exit.

Second thing:
Also your `end` variable in main is not initialized, maybe you missed this `end = getchar()` in the `if` condition.
If this isn't initialized might cause a seg-fault too.

Third thing:
`\n` in `scanf` is really required? If this is present it will take the 3rd input as the input for the next `scanf` and won't prompt you for the input for that scanf.
i.e. here currently the 3rd input will go into the no. of organisms without being prompted for.

Comment: `\n` is worse than not required, it will require you to enter a line TWICE, although only the first one is used.

Comment: So I should put an if statement in that for loop to only do table[][] = life only if the height and width are > 0 but < HEIGHT and WIDTH?

Comment: You should consider equal to `0` also :)

Comment: I put 'if ((height >= 0 && height =< HEIGHT) && (width >= 0 && width =< WIDTH))' on top of the tableA part is that right?